# Marketmore cucumber only has female flowers

Tags: pollination, cucumbers

A month ago I've purchased 2 marketmore seedling from the garden center, but so far there has been no male flower. Every flower is a female flower. I googled online and did not find that there was a parthenocarpic marketmore variety. Has anyone seen this happen before?

I just have my fingers crossed and hope that either it is parthenocarpic or the male flower are coming soon....

Its really odd to just have female flower especially for the first blooms

Answer (score 1):

I finally spotted 1 male flower, proves that it isn't parthenocarpic. Still odd how the female flower > male flower by A LOT